# how to center a div horizontally, vertically, and maintain 1:1 aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I wish to have a canvas inside of a div which is centered and regardless of its scale, maintains a 1:1 aspect ratio.

By creating a containing div with the following style rules, I am able to get the child element (the canvas) to be centered vertically and horizontally.

```
display: "flex",
alignItems: "center",
justifyContent: "center",
```

However, after much googling, I'm unable to find a way of enforcing an aspect ratio.  There is some odd way of using top-padding, but it doesn't seem to work in the case of flex box.

I may decide to change the relative size of the canvas in its containing div, but I'd like it to remain centered and presever a 1:1 aspect ratio.  What css rules can meet those constraints?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `max-width` and `max-height`.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:#429bf4;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img class='image' src='http://via.placeholder.com/300x300'>
</div>
```

`Flex` Example

```css
.main {
  width: 200px;
}
.aspect1-1 {
  width:100%;
  padding-top:100%;
  position: relative;
}

.aspect1-1 div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color:#429bf4;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="aspect1-1">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your main `div` is full screen, you can use `vmin`. You need to set the `canvas` `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` to `0` so the size will not be responsive, set `min-width` to `0` to narrow past the implied width of the `canvas` (`300px`), define the width with `flex-basis` and the height with `height` (same as `flex-basis` for a 1:1 ratio):

```
flex: 0 0 100vmin;
min-width: 0;
height: 100vmin;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.outerdiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

canvas.center {
  flex: 0 0 100vmin;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 100vmin;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
  <canvas class="center"></canvas>
</div>
```

And if you want a margin, use `calc()` with two times the margin:

```
flex: 0 0 calc(100vmin - 10em);
min-width: 0;
height: calc(100vmin - 10em);
margin: 5em;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.outerdiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

canvas.center {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100vmin - 10em);
  min-width: 0;
  height: calc(100vmin - 10em);
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
  <canvas class="center"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to achieve aspect ratio that doesn't rely on viewport relative sizes?